# How to use .Select to achieve .ThenInclude?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to Read Related Data but only read the specific field.
if use include theninclude will read all fiedl.
so I use .Select, but how to use .Select to achieve .ThenInclude?
Thanks~

```
var ViewModel = await _context.A_Table
                .Select(s => new ViewModel {
                    A_TableId = s.Id,
                    B_Table = s.B_Table,
                    C_Table = ??? (s.B_Table.C_Table is wrong)
                });
```

```
public class A_Table
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public IList<B_Table> B_Table { get; set; }
    }

public class B_Table
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public int A_TableId { get; set; }
        public int C_TableId { get; set; }
        public C_Table C_Table { get; set; }
    }

public class C_Table
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public B_Table B_Table { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: `(s.B_Table.C_Table is wrong)` why is it wrong? What field do you want to read? How doesn't `s.B_Table.C_Table.Field1` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

this is because `B_Table` property is list of `B_Table` so when you want to access `C_Table` property inside it you have to specify which item in the list you want to access

**e.g.** `s.B_Table[0].C_Table` to access first item in the list.

if you want aggregate all items in side the list you can use `SelectMany` using Linq inside namespace `System.Linq`

**e.g.** `s.B_Table.SelectMany(B_Table => B_Table.C_Table).ToList()`